# Embedding image sequences and video textures

Tags: blend-files

Just wondering if there is a way to embed image sequences and video textures into a .blend file. I am working on a blender file for projection mapping so have animations stored as image sequences and videos within materials.

I know that you can embed single images and video editing videos within .blend files through external data > pack all into .blend, however this doesn't work for image sequences and videos within a material.

I am asking because working from home on certain days a week is making transferring these files a bit of a pain and I can't seem to figure out git for storing my files.